# Modification of Future Value

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this you have to add the annual contribution to the beginning of the year (the principal total) before computing interest for that year.

I am stuck and need help.  This is what I have so far:

```
def main(): 

    print("Future Value Program - Version 2")
    print()
    principal = eval(input("Enter Initial Principal:"))
    contribution = eval(input("Enter Annual Contribution:"))
    apr = eval(input("Enter Annual Percentage Rate (decimal):"))
    yrs = eval(input("Enter Number of Years:"))
    for k in range (1, yrs):
        principal= principal * (1 + apr)
    print()
    print( yrs,) ": Amount $", int(principal * 100 + 0.5)/100)

main()
```

It is supposed to look like this:

```
Future Value Program - Version 2 

Enter Initial Principal: 1000.00
Enter Annual Contribution: 100.00
Enter Annual Percentage Rate (decimal): 0.034
Enter Number of Years: 5 

Year 1: Amount $ 1137.4
Year 2: Amount $ 1279.47
Year 3: Amount $ 1426.37
Year 4: Amount $ 1578.27
Year 5: Amount $ 1735.33

The value in 5 years is $ 1735.33
```

Comment: and what does it actually produce?

Comment: Don't use eval on input, cast to float.

Comment: It looks like you want your print statement to be inside your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example that produces the expected output:

```
def main(): 
    print("Future Value Program - Version 2")
    print()
    principal = float(input("Enter Initial Principal: "))
    contribution = float(input("Enter Annual Contribution: "))
    apr = float(input("Enter Annual Percentage Rate (decimal): "))
    yrs = int(input("Enter Number of Years: "))
    print()
    for yr in range(1, yrs + 1):
        principal += contribution
        principal = int(((principal * (1 + apr)) * 100) + 0.5) / 100
        print("Year {0}: Amount $ {1}".format(yr, principal))
    print()
    print("The value in {0} years is $ {1}".format(yrs, principal))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There were a few problems with the example in the question:

1. A syntax error in the print statement on line 12. Calling `print` with parens means all the arguments should be enclosed inside the parens.  Python interpreted the errant paren as the end of arguments passed to `print`.
2. As noted by others, you shouldn't call `eval` on the inputs. Call `float` for floating point numbers, `int` for integers.
3. The `range` operator had an off by one error.
4. As noted by others, `print` is called outside of the loop, so intermediate states of the principal aren't output.
5. As far as basic maths, it seems as though adding the contribution was left out.
6. As per the expected output, the final `print` was missing.